# What is the UrlFetch Post Size Limit?

Tags: post, google-apps-script, urlfetch

I'm trying to find out what the [`UrlFetchApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_urlfetchapp#fetch)'s POST Size Limit is?  A script uploads a few emailed attachments to a web service, and is getting back the following error:

> "Limit Exceeded: UrlFetch Post Size. (line XX)".

I have no way to figure this out short of sending a bunch of different sized files to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximum size you can POST is 10 MB 
Please see https://docs.google.com/macros/dashboard where you can get documented Apps Script quota and limits information.

Comment: Thanks Srik. Would you know of a way I can check the post payload's size?  I base64 encoded a 6MB PDF file into an XML object, and then post the XML as a string to the web service.  Unfortunately it's still giving me size errors.

Answer (score 2):

updated information: now it's 50MB
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations

Answer (score 0):

The quotas details can be found here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations

It is 10MB max URL Fetch POST size